# Add own app to the whatsapp audio selection

Tags: java, android, android-intent, whatsapp, intentfilter

How can I add my own app to the whatsapp audio selection like [this application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.bananadevs.audiosoundrecordershareforwhatsapp) in android (with java)?

I know, I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52748257/how-can-i-add-an-app-to-the-whatsapp-audio-selection) already but I didn't get a useful answer. I didn't think that it could work, but I found this app and it works on my android phone (Huawei VNC-L31/Huawei P9 Lite, Android 7.0). ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wt6bE.png))

I tried it with the one-to-one intent filter from the manifest of this app but it didn't work.

Thanks for grammar correction ;)

Answer (score 0):

in whatsapp(like app) do like this on audio selection

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("audio/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Audio "), reqCode);
```

and in your application create an activity which contains list of audio.

add code like this in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
 <activity
            android:name=".activity.AudioListActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

and in your `AudioListActivity` [return result](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters#ReturnResult) to other app on selection of audio or as you required.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<data android:scheme="content"/>
<data android:host="media"/>
<data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
<data android:mimeType="application/ogg"/>
<data android:mimeType="application/x-ogg"/>
<data android:mimeType="application/itunes"/>
</intent-filter>
```